# How to center handles without label in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to have a legend with titles for columns and rows, how can I make them compact and centered (check the attached image)?

```
colors = ['tab:purple', 'tab:blue', 'tab:green', 'tab:olive', 'tab:orange', 'tab:red']
labels = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5, -1, -1):
    p1 = ax.plot([1], [1], '-', color=colors[i], label=labels[i], linewidth=2.75)
    
    
for i in range(5, -1, -1):
    p2 = ax.plot([1], [1], 's', color=colors[i], label=labels[i], linewidth=2.75)


h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ph = [plt.plot([],marker="", ls="")[0]]*9
handles = ph[:8] + h[:6] + ph[8:] + h[6:]
labels = [""] + l[:6] + ["Optimized Data"] + [""]*6 + ["Not Optimized Data"] + [""]*6
leg = plt.legend(handles, labels, ncol=3)

for vpack in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children():
    for hpack in vpack.get_children():
        hpack.get_children()[0].set_width(0)
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LziK.png)